# Output Joomla subform

Tags: php, joomla, joomla-extensions, joomla-component

OK, I have tried the info from another suggestion on stackexchange, but I seem to be missing something.

I have a subform in an admin view for a component I am working on (they were previously repeatable fields). Admin works perfect, but I am having trouble getting the json to display correctly on the frontend site view.

The fields that are being pulled into the view are in a layout, so it's a little different than in the site view ($displayData instead of $items).

In the db I have a field called appliances, and 4 items in the field are `{"appliances1":{"appliance_type":"Dishwasher"},"appliances2":{"appliance_type":"Range"},"appliances3":{"appliance_type":"Microwave"},"appliances4":{"appliance_type":"Washer/Dryer"}}`

OK. That looks good and properly formatted.

On the frontend, in the layout for a view, I have:

```
<?php
print_r($displayData->appliances); 

foreach ($displayData->appliances as $item) : ?> <div>
<p>
<?php echo $displayData->appliance_type; ?>
</p>
</div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

the `print_r` shows:

```
Appliances Array ( [appliances1] => Array ( [appliance_type] => Dishwasher ) [appliances2] => Array ( [appliance_type] => Range ) [appliances3] => Array ( [appliance_type] => Microwave ) [appliances4] => Array ( [appliance_type] => Washer/Dryer ) )
```

OK. again, that looks good. I'll remove that as soon at its working properly.

The problem is that

```
<p>
<?php echo $displayData->appliance_type; ?>
</p>
```

doesn't display anything.

I can see in the code, that it's doing the foreach correctly, but it's not grabbing anything from the array:

```
Array ( [appliances1] => Array ( [appliance_type] => Dishwasher ) [appliances2] => Array ( [appliance_type] => Range ) [appliances3] => Array ( [appliance_type] => Microwave ) [appliances4] => Array ( [appliance_type] => Washer/Dryer ) ) <div> <p> </p> </div> <div> <p> </p> </div> <div> <p> </p> </div> <div> <p> </p> </div>
```

Any thoughts on what I may be missing?

Comment: Try `<?= $displayData->appliances1->appliance_type ?>`, though print_r is showing arrays :/ `<?= $displayData['appliances1']['appliance_type'] ?>`

Comment: Potential problem with they is subforms add a different number after appliances for each new entry: appliances1, appliances2, appliances3, etc.

Comment: You might need to pass it through array_walk or such and normalise it for use. You cant simply skip a level and expect it to work.

Comment: `\Joomla\Utilities\ArrayHelper::getColumn('appliances', 'appliance_type');` might work. The way it adds them numbers at the end is not user friendly.

Comment: I agree that the added number don't make it very friendly, but that is how subforms store the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK. I knew I wasn't going to be able to sleep until I tackled this. It may not be the cleanest, yet, but this works for outputting data from a Joomla Subform:

```
<?php $records = $displayData->appliances; ?>
<?php foreach ($records as $key => $value) {
    echo $value["appliance_type"] ."<br>";
    }
?>
```

Result:

```
Appliances

Dishwasher
Range
Microwave
Washer/Dryer
```

Comment: Thanks for coming back and posting the answer